# Карта перекрывает NavigationBar (ios)

Tags: navigationbar

Здравствуйте. Изначально я встроил в свое приложение ios карты от google. Вот небольшая часть кода:

```
@implementation ViewController{
GMSMapView *mapView_;
}
```

...

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

self.view = mapView_;
```

}

Но теперь, когда я добавляю  NavigationBar в тот же  NavigationController где находиться карта, то получается так, что NavigationBar остается за картой, говоря по другому карта его перекрывает. Пытался решить проблему разными путями, но ничего не выходит. 
Есть у кого нибудь идеи как решить данную проблему?

Если кому нибудь даст подсказку:

Когда я запускаю приложение на эмуляторе, то пока не подгрузилась карта я вижу Навигационный бар 
[image: До]

[image: После]

Answer (score 1):

После недолгих мучении. Ответ был найден. До этого я просто заменял  self.view на гугло карты.

Для того, что бы не происходило перекрывание кнопок, текст и т.д. картой нужно добавить еще один view и связать его с GMSMapView.

[image: фото_1]

после связать карту программно и задать еи начальные настройки:

```
IBOutlet GMSMapView *mapView_;
```

Настройки могут быть:

```
GMSCameraPosition *camera = [GMSCameraPosition cameraWithLatitude:45.24 longitude:19.84 zoom:6]; [self.mapView_ setCamera:camera];
```